# Running repeating animation in Android using a thread/runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, memory-leaks, runnable

My goal is to have a thread running that plays a sound then chooses a random animation and a random image and displays them.

It is currently working, but I was wondering if there is a better way. I have a Hacker's understanding of threading (as in, I only know that this works), so I'd appreciate some feedback. Also, I've been having issues with memory overflow in my app, is there a better way to manage this Activity memory-wise? Thank you so much!

```
public int[] images = {R.drawable.splat0,R.drawable.splat1,R.drawable.splat2,R.drawable.splat3,
        R.drawable.splat4,R.drawable.splat5,R.drawable.splat6,R.drawable.splat7,R.drawable.splat8,
        R.drawable.splat9};
public int[] anims= {R.anim.splat0,R.anim.splat1,R.anim.splat2,
        R.anim.splat3,R.anim.splat4,R.anim.splat5,R.anim.splat6};

MediaManager mp;
Handler tick_Handler = new Handler();
MyThread tick_thread = new MyThread();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mp = new MediaManager();

    image = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.mainActivitySplat);

    tick_Handler.post(tick_thread);
}

@Override 
public void onStop(){
    tick_Handler.removeCallbacks(tick_thread);
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    tick_Handler.post(tick_thread);
    super.onResume();
}

private class MyThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {     
        mp.playSoundClip(MainActivity.this,R.raw.swoosh);
        image.setBackgroundResource(images[(int)(Math.random()*splats.length)]);    
        Animation myAnim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,splatAnim[(int)(Math.random()*splatAnim.length)]);
        splat.startAnimation(myAnim);
        tick_Handler.postDelayed(tick_thread, 3500);
    }
}
```

Edit:
I have discovered this is a BAD way of using the Thread. MyThread holds an implicit reference to the Activity, and causes a massive memory leak. By changing the class to private static MyThread I solve the leak, but I have not yet figured out how to get the desired behavior this way. Will update later.

Answer (score 0):

use a flag like
    `boolean isActibityKilled=true //when in onstop`
use it in the runnable to check  if activity is running or not if activity is not running , or it is stopped then kill your thread

Comment: Haha actually I just fixed the original issue of the thread continuing to run when the activity closed. I found the handler was only restarting when onCreate was called. So if I had finish() the page and restart it then the thread would run, but hitting home button would not restart the thread when user reactivated MainActivity. By moving handler.post to onResume, it is now working properly. I appreciate the info though! How could I set a boolean activityRunning = aMethodThatTellsIfActivityIsCurrent() as you suggest?

Comment: Instead of removing the callback in the `onStop` method, it is best practice to use the `onPause`.

Comment: In android life cycle onDestroy is called in onDestroy() The OS decides when things "go away." The onDestroy is there to let your app have a final chance to clean things up before the activity does get destroyed. there you can set the **boolean**